# Mapbox - Load an image to a certain pixel size and not a relate size?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

i'm using [mapbox](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-image/) and using the `map.loadImage` and I don't see a way the image I load be set a certain pixel height and width. they have `"icon-size"` but that scales the original size of the icon by the provided factor.

Comment: Is there a reason you feel like you need to do this by using an explicit pixel size? Using `"icon-size"` to scale by the factor will make sure your map & icon look similar regardless of device/screen variation.

Comment: @riastrad images of different pixel sizes aren't show as one standard size. I don't have control over the size of the image so I wanted to set it

Comment: In that case, I would recommend you modify the image before you call `map.loadImage`. GL JS does it's best to ensure fidelity of whatever static elements you provide, so outside of scaling the image by a factor it doesn't really include methods for image manipulation after images have been added to the map.